# primefaces dataTable lazy liveScroll not working properly

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I have some unexpected behavior when using primefaces dataTable with liveScroll enabled in combination with a lazy data model. Let me show the example first in order to specify what kind of problem there is.

I created a small alternative of the primefaces showcase code. This is the page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head />
<body>
  <h:form id="form" style="width:300px;height:300px">
    <p:dataTable id="carTable" var="car" value="#{carBean.carTableModel}" scrollable="true" lazy="true"
      scrollHeight="200" scrollRows="10" liveScroll="true" rowKey="#{car.id}">
      <p:column headerText="Id">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
      </p:column>
      <p:column headerText="Brand">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
      </p:column>
      <p:column headerText="Action">
        <h:commandButton value="Go!" action="#{carBean.go(car)}" update="goneCar" />
      </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
    <h:outputText id="goneCar" value="Last car gone: #{carBean.goneCar.id} #{carBean.goneCar.brand}" />
  </h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Next is the carBean backing bean code. Kept really simple. Method call log is abstract.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "carBean")
@ViewScoped
public class CarBean implements Serializable {
  private final static String[] BRANDS = {"BMW", "Mercedes", "Volvo",
    "Audi", "Renault", "Fiat", "Volkswagen", "Honda", "Jaguar", "Ford"};
  private Car goneCar;
  private LazyCarDataModel carTableModel;
  public CarBean() {
    Car[] cars = new Car[200];
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
      cars[i] = new Car(i, BRANDS[(int) (Math.random() * 10)]);
    }
    carTableModel = new LazyCarDataModel(cars);
  }
  public LazyCarDataModel getCarTableModel() {
    return carTableModel;
  }

  public void go(Car car) {
    log("go with " + car.getId());
    goneCar = car;
  }
  public Car getGoneCar() {
    return goneCar;
  }
}
```

And finally the LazyCarDataModel class. I added some logging (abstract) to explain my behavior. See that I added getRowCount which was not added in the primefaces manual. If not added I do not see any results at all.

```
public class LazyCarDataModel extends LazyDataModel<Car> {

  private Car[] datasource;

  public LazyCarDataModel(Car[] datasource) {
    this.datasource = datasource;
  }

  @Override
  public int getRowCount() {
    log("getRowCount");
    return datasource.length;
  }

  @Override
  public Car getRowData(String rowKey) {
    log("getRowData " + rowKey);
    return datasource[Integer.parseInt(rowKey)];
  }

  @Override
  public Object getRowKey(Car car) {
    log("getRowKey: "+car.getId());
    return car.getId();
  }

  @Override
  public List<Car> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, 
       SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {
    int last = Math.min(first + pageSize, datasource.length);
    log("refresh page " + first + " " + pageSize);
    return Arrays.asList(Arrays.copyOfRange(datasource, first, last));
  }
}
```

When first fetching the table I see a table with 10 items loaded, not all shown because of the smaller viewport. Following is in my logging:

```
refresh page 0 10
getRowCount
getRowCount
```

Next I click on the first Go! button. I see following, where the number of times getRowCount is called bothers me but 'go with 0' is correct however refresh page 0 10 is not really required here.

```
getRowCount
getRowCount
getRowCount
go with 0
refresh page 0 10
getRowCount
getRowCount
```

I scroll to the last element in the table and a next page of 10 items is loaded.

```
refresh page 10 10
```

Looks ok. Now I click on button Go! of row with id==6. This is in the logging:

```
getRowCount
getRowCount
getRowCount
go with 16
refresh page 0 10
getRowCount
getRowCount
```

This is wrong. Go with 16 should have been go with 6. Now it also loads items from 0 over length==10, the first page again. Clicking the same button again now gives:

```
getRowCount
getRowCount
getRowCount
go with 6
refresh page 0 10
getRowCount
getRowCount
```

Which is fine but again a refresh is not very efficient. Also wrong is that the table now shows rows 0 up till 9 and then 0 up till 9 again?

Can somebody explain me what is wrong in my code? I use primefaces-5.2. How can I use this livescroll and lazy (paged) model in a solid way?

Many thanks!

Comment: tried PF5.3? (Try, not use in production, just to see if it is fixed)

Comment: I tried PF5.3 and the behavior looks the same to me.